# Upload photo to Facebook with Facebook Android SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook, photo, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-java-api

I'm new to Android. I'm searching for load photo to facebook by authorization, getting access_token. How to do this? Please give me a sample code in Java.

Comment: Sanjana, you should accept an answer. It helps you and others who help out on Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Just posted here the simple way to upload a photo:

[android facebook publish photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647767/android-facebook-publish-photo)

Code:

```
byte[] data = null;

Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoToPost);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
params.putByteArray("picture", data);

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

Comment: how can I add a description to uploaded photo?

Comment: Havent tried but im sure if you look on the facebook dev docs, there will be something you can add to the params.

Comment: did you figure this out? The part about the description?

Comment: I havent. Sorry. I have been busy now with other projects. Did you get anywhere on it?

Comment: Does this require to go through the process of registering the app?

Comment: params.putString("caption", "description here"); for adding description

Comment: how to share more than one image to fb..please help

Answer (score 8):

```
facebook.authorize(FbdemoActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                });


public void postImageonWall() {

           byte[] data = null;

             Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/viewitems.png");
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
             data = baos.toByteArray();


             Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
             params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
             params.putByteArray("picture", data);

             AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
             mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);


    }


public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

here is the whole code try it it will definately work for you and it is work for me also

Comment: What is BaseRequestListener ?

Comment: Your example works for me. But in extra i want to post the simple message with that photo post. So how it is possible ? Any idea ? give answer here.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585043/android-how-to-post-the-message-with-the-image-post-on-facebook

Comment: photos.upload isn't a deprecated Legacy Rest Api method?

Comment: This code does work with the following caveats.  1. I put the facebook.authorize() call inside an onClick().  I added the other 2 methods to my existing Activity.  2. It results in an out of memory error if you repeat the upload more than once per application run.

Comment: android not recognizing the BaseRequestListener. Where this class exist?

I need a complete code. I dont know where facebook object come from? e.g facebook.authorize()

Comment: how to share more the one image to facebook

Comment: @MuhammadAamirAli same problem! Cannot resolve symbol 'BaseRequestListener'

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way for you is to use the existing SDK, something like that:
http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/
http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Android

The more flexible way is to implement the API yourself, here are the docs that will be useful:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: Looking at the FB api, I don't see any way to upload an image. I only see that you can pass an image URL as a parameter, but not the image data itself. Or have I overlooked anything?

Comment: how to share more than one image to fb..please help

Answer (score 3):

Successfully i have uploaded the photos on facebook wall
I used the following code.

**In your Main Activity do the following;**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            authenticatedFacebook.authorize(Facebooktest2Activity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        postImage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Posted on Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

    });


        }
});






}

public void postImage(){
     byte[] data = null;               

        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/img.jpg");
        //Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);             
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();              
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);              
        data = baos.toByteArray();                
        Bundle params = new Bundle();              
        params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, authenticatedFacebook.getAccessToken());              
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");              
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);               
        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(authenticatedFacebook);              
        mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);   

}


public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseKeyListener implements RequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Bitmap getInputType(Bitmap img) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Surely This code will help you.

Comment: I used this code, and got exception as  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:103)
  at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:234)
 at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native Method)
in this line bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

Comment: authenticatedFacebook is what..it gives mee an error..please help

Comment: what if we have to share more then one image to facebook..please help

Answer (score 3):

If you want to publish a photo with a description you can do this :

```
public void publishPhoto(byte[] imgData, string message) {

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner (facebook);

Bundle parameters = new Bundle ();
parameters.putString (Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
parameters.putString ("message", message);
parameters.putByteArray ("source", imgData);

mAsyncRunner.Request ("me/photos", parameters, "POST", new RequestListener (), null);
}
```

Comment: +1 That's it! Thank you. After sifting through so many people using the legacy api, this one is finally showing the Graph api solution.