# How to implement Facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook

How can I implement Facebook login in android?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Android - Upload photo to Facebook with Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-in-java/3109533#3109533)