# android fb-connect layout disordering issue

Tags: android, fbconnect

I am using fb-connect for android app problem is when keyboards gets open layout distorted ??

I think they are opening facebook login page in browser any quick fix to add done button and layout disordering after keyboard get open

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2493f17000.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2493f17000.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Answer (score 0):

That's why I don't use fb-connect but call API methods directly. fb-connect uses old facebook API not the Graph API, so it seems to be outdated now.
There's also another FB SDK implementation from FB itelf, you may try it.
Links here [Android - Upload photo to Facebook with Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-in-java/3109533#3109533).