# Updating your facebook status?

Tags: android, facebook

My application intends to update the Facebook status to the area in which my cellphone is. How do I go about it?

From where should I start & in what direction should I proceed? I am able to get the GPS locations. Only can't figure out how to link my application to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Android - Upload photo to Facebook with Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-in-java/3109533#3109533)