# how to Upload Photo in facebook from gallery in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have to do facebook android integration project. But I have to pass simple live image URl than send it. But how to pick image in gallery and upload to facebook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Picking images is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android) question. Try to search before you ask something.

Comment: ya i pick photo from gallery but how to upload this photo in facebook??

Comment: oh, my god. Do you know that search exists? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-in-java