# Upload a photo from android on facebook

Tags: android

I want to upload photos from my android app to my friends' walls,timelines. Please direct me where to start.

Comment: [google](http://www.google.co.in) is best place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples of this online, even if you just check stackoverflow you will find numerous similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-with-facebook-android-sdk) one

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) is a tutorial that will give you everything you need to understand, from start to finish, each step of the process and more if you want your application to do more than just upload photos

Comment: glad to help, but @Ferdau is right, stackoverflow is not for questions like this, next time you should really do a bit of research yourself and if you run into problems then post the problems up