# Android post image on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, image

I have tried many code to send the image on facebook wall but it is not working.
  I am using this code

```
Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(shareDialogContext.getResources(),R.drawable.splash);

byte[] byetArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(shareDialogContext,bitmap);
params.putByteArray("picture",byetArray);
objFacebook.request(profileID + "me/photos", params, "POST");
public byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
 ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() * 
     bitmap.getHeight());
     bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, buffer);
     return buffer.toByteArray();
```

}

Please suggest any useful code.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't [hackbook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/Hackbook.java) example do exactly what you want?

```
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                try {
                    params.putByteArray("photo",
                            Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), photoUri));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                params.putString("caption", "FbAPIs Sample App photo upload");
                Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
                        new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 try 
 {
     params.putByteArray("photo",Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), photoUri));
 }
 catch (IOException e) 
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 params.putString("caption", "Through My Android Application");
 Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

Possible duplicate : [Android - Upload photo to Facebook with Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-with-facebook-android-sdk)