# Android activity, share a user photo on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to share a user photo with facebook (source from existing photo or new photo with camera).
The share contains:

- name app
- link app
- title and/or description
- photo

Is it possibile without facebook login into android app?
I tried with FacebookDialog but the values that i set into doesn't work.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                        .setApplicationName("SuperSelfie")
                        .setName("Hi All:")
                        .setPicture(fileUri.getPath())
                        .setDescription("Selfie...")
                        .setLink(
                                "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=project.stats")
                        .build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

What is necessary?

- FacebookDialog without login
- Facebook login?
- Open Graph?
- others?

Please help me..
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Upload photo to Facebook with Facebook Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-with-facebook-android-sdk)

Comment: This question is different. I asked if possible share photo to Facebook without the authorization, and the best way for this.

Comment: You can not share without authorization, you can not even log in without permission

Comment: With shareDialog i can share to facebook without app login...